# Lightning detection

Tags: detection, lightning, magnetic-flux

I am planning to build a device that has a capability of early detection of a lightning. Also we want to measure the magnitude of the lightning and can anyone suggest a way to measure the magnitude of a lightning using magnetic flux induced by that lightning?

Comment: What is *early* detection? Before it happened?

Comment: Ever tried listing to an AM radio when a thunder storm is in the neighborhood?

Comment: @Trevor The problem is that the same effect is achieved with a battery and wire spark near the radio :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. true, issue would be separating local vs distant noises.

Comment: Magnetic flux isn't induced, it is created by current. OK what level of current pulse are you talking about, how high in metres is the current pulse (from the cloud) and how far away is the measuring equipment. So the worst cases are zero amps, zero height and infinite distance. What do you want to achieve? Next, work out the peak flux density using biot-savart and then work out the maximum rate of change of that flux density due to the lightning lasting a finite length of time. And finally design a coil (possibly mutiturn) that can produce a decent voltage based on Faraday's induction law.

Comment: Multiple detectors separated by as large a distance as practical.  If you could place them 1 mile apart, you could get differences of at least 5 microseconds to use to calculate direction. Then you just have the practical problems of getting your detected signals to your processor of a mile of wire without them (the signals) getting squished by all manner of inductive and capacitive effects as well as simple resistive losses - not to mention the noise the wires could pickup.

Comment: If you want to detect lightning before it happens, then you need to measure the local electric field.  This can be done with a [field mill](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_mill) electrometer

Comment: [This site gived some tips on detecting lighting with an electrometer.](http://alancordwell.co.uk/Legacy/electronics/lightning.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple RF inductor will work as an antenna. Or really any antenna for that matter.

Check out the [AS3935](http://ams.com/eng/Products/Wireless-Connectivity/Wireless-Sensor-Connectivity/AS3935) they use a simple RF coil to detect lightning. You could use your own radio detection circuit instead of the AS3935. Here is some info on the [schematic with a BOM](https://ams.com/eng/content/download/542043/1525417) it has info on the RF inductor.

Here is some info on another group that builds [antennas and stations for lightning](http://www.blitzortung.org/Documents/TOA_Blitzortung.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

You can't reliably detect lightning before it happens.  You can detect the conditions that make lightning likely.

A common method for assessing the immediate danger from lighting is a *field mill*.  This is a device for measuring the local strength of the electric field.  You might think that measuring the voltage of two plates some distance apart is all that's needed, but it's not so simple.  The problem is that any method for measuring the voltage will eventually bleed off the charge.

A field mill is two plates, but they rotate so as to regularly swap which one is high and which one is low.  By doing that, you get a AC signal.  That signal is still high impedance, but by constantly flipping the plates, you get a continual signal, even if the charge is drained in the process of measuring.

Answer (score 1):

The most practical method of detecting lightning is using a VLF radio receiver with a directional antenna.

Most of the RF energy released is under 50 kHz and there are multiple products that provide both amplitude and direction sensing.

There is also considerable research in this field (though why you appear not to have looked this up is troublesome). Perhaps start [here](http://www.ijaiem.org/ITechCON-2014/EXTC-02.pdf).